# Using QT Framework or Android Framework For Render Update Application

Tags: android, qt, layout, frameworks, render

I have a development question. I have an application written for Android using the android SDK and Java programming language. The app layout looks like the following (mock layout):

[image]

From the image you can see that I have essentially a lot of image views. At the very bottom those are image buttons. So, these images are not added in statically. Rather, I receive information from another Android Service (connected via Thrift) that tells me what data I'm working with. Then, I tell the service what data I want to render by sending out render requests. I then will receive render job replies (via callback) telling me where in another shared memory process, I can pull the data. I use JNI to pull the image byte data. I then use that byte data to make a Bitmap image and then populate the appropriate image view/button. It is important to note that these render job updates can come in frequently, say every half a second. Which then I have to update the Image views/buttons.

The problem is the UX response time. Often times, the UI is very sluggish or not as responsive as it should be. When the images update to different images it can take like a second or two to update. I want this to update almost immediately. I feel like the UI thread is being really taxed. The layouts dimens are static (no wrap content anywhere) and I try not to layer the layout. Is there another framework I can use to make this seem not as sluggish, say QT Framework and use more native calls to handle the job updates? Heres the process:

1. Make Render Requests (over Thrift to Android Service)
2. wait for reply (pretty fast at getting reply)
3. Get Render Job Update (callback on Thrift)
4. Call JNI method to pull image byte data
5. Update Image view/button

Comment: Would really like it if someone had some kind of experience or good understanding of QT vs standard Android UI framework

Comment: Will continue to update comment area until someone has had experience here.